# Spark streaming run processing at 00:00 every hour

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to use Spark to perform processing with streaming data once every hour but I want it to start as close to xx:00:00 (xx being an hour id). Is that possible or that's against Spark ideology?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a DStream with a streaming interval of 60 minutes, the micro-batch will trigger every hour on the hour.

`val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Minutes(60))`

If you start the app at example `12:29:55` the app will wait until `13:00:00` until the first microbatch starts.

The next batch will be `14:00:00` and so on.

Comment: That's almost right. To be more precise, if you start processing at 12:29:55 at time 13:00:00 it will take all of the collected batches and will aggregate them. From then all of the batches will be processed xx:00:00-xx:59:59.
It's weird that this feature is not mentioned anywhere in documentation